# "Fundamental theorem for Hopf modules"

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories, symmetric-monoidal-categories

I am studying [Hopf algebras in categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_algebra#Hopf_algebras_in_braided_monoidal_categories), and I hope, somebody could help me with the following.

Joost Vercruysse in his paper [Hopf algebras---Variant notions and reconstruction theorems](https://arxiv.org/abs/1202.3613) writes (Theorem 3.6) that the caracterization of Hopf algebras as bialgebras whose category of Hopf modules possesses some "good" properties is generalized to Hopf algebras in "arbitrary" braided categories:

> Let $H$ be a bialgebra in a braided monoidal category $C$ with equalizers, then the following statements are equivalent:
>
> (i) the functor $(−)^{coH}:C_H^H\to C$ is fully faithful;
>
> (ii) the pair $(− ⊗ H,(−)^{coH})$ is an equivalence of categories between $C$ and $C_H^H$;
>
> (iii) $(m ⊗ H)\circ (H ⊗ ∆) : H ⊗ H \to H ⊗ H$ is a $C$-isomorphism;
>
> (iv) $H$ admits an antipode, i.e. $H$ is a Hopf algebra in $C$

(here $C_H^H$ is the category of "right-right" Hopf modules over $H$, and $(−)^{coH}$ is the right adjoint functor for $− ⊗ H$).

Vercruysse mentiones this without proof. I think, this is the effect of folklore, when something obvious for specialists is not clear for people who are not aware with the context, but I don't understand how this is proved. Could anybody enlighten me? If this is easy you can just explain this here, but if not, I hope, you could give me a reference.

Comment: Do you know the proof in the classical/Vect case ? I think it should extends fairly easily to this more general braided case just by writing things diagrammatically. If you're asking for a reference already for that there are many, e.g. section 3.2 in http://homepages.vub.ac.be/~scaenepe/Hopfalgebra.pdf . More precisely the equivalences between (i) and (ii), and between (iii) and (iv) are fairly obvious, and the reference above implies $(ii)\Leftrightarrow (iv)$.

Comment: Adrien, thank you! This looks very useful!

Comment: ...Although I don't see how this text implies $(ii)\Rightarrow(iv)$.

Comment: Regarding the braided case, maybe the following article can be of some interest to the OP: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/267673758_Hopf_modules_in_the_braided_monoidal_category_L_M.                                                            (although i am not sure if the implication $(ii)\Rightarrow(iv)$ is made explicit).

Comment: P.S. Joost Vercruysse sent me his paper named "AANVULLINGEN OP “HOPF ALGEBRAS EN QUANTUM GROEPEN”, where the necessary explanations are given, so this answers the question. I only don't know whether this text was published or not, so it's not clear for me how to refer to it.